# Why do the loops in this code not work?

Tags: vb.net, loops

I don't understand why it doesn't work, I've tried a For loop, do until loop and do while loop but they just don't want to work. Without the loops, it works perfectly fine, but I want to use loops to reduce the lines of code that are being used. The "Hub" calls this class using `MoveHub.MoveUp(10)` and the same goes for `MoveDown` but it's like it does nothing at all. Any suggestions?

I've tested everything out in the Hub form, the code there is not the problem. It's the MoveHub class that causes issues.

Here's the code:

```
Public Class MoveHub

    Public pos As Integer
    Public toggle As Boolean

    Public Sub MoveUp(speed As Integer)
        If (pos > 0) Then
            '  For Me.pos = 9 To 0
            Do Until pos = 0
                pos -= 1
                Hub.Location = (New Point(Hub.Location.X, Hub.Location.Y - speed))
                If pos = 0 Then
                    Hub.DragPic.Image = My.Resources.DropPicture4
                    toggle = True
                End If
            Loop
            ' Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub MoveDown(speed As Integer)
        If (pos < 10) Then
            'For Me.pos = 0 To 9
            Do Until pos = 9
                pos += 1
                Hub.Location = (New Point(Hub.Location.X, Hub.Location.Y + speed))
                If pos = 9 Then
                    Hub.DragPic.Image = My.Resources.DropPicture4_Up
                    toggle = False
                End If
            Loop
            'Next
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at the start of your functions and then step over each line while inspecting your `pos` value?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to learn to use the debugger!  it is an important skill any *professional programmer or serious enthusiast* must have

Comment: Please read [How To Debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: With the help of the breakpoint I managed to figure out why it wasn't working, thanks for the suggestions guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling MoveUp(10) and asusme that the loop will run 10 times.

This assumption is incorrect. Because Parameter that receive passed value 10 is speed. While the Loop is being controlled by variable pos.

If my assumption is not correct then you need to provide the code calling these methods and where the value of pos is being set.

Comment: Value is being set when the main Hub loads; MoveHub.pos = 9.
I'm saying MoveUp(10) so that it moves up by 10 pixels every time it loops.

Comment: After saying that I realised my mistake, I didn't write Movehub.pos = 9, I wrote pos = 9, whoops... It works now! Anyway thanks for trying to help!